# Understanding Brushes in WPF

Tags: wpf

Beside SolidColorBrush, LinearGradientBrush, and RadialGradientBrush there are also three other types of brushes:

- VisualBrush,
- DrawingBrush,
- and ImageBrush.

The first three types are self-explanatory. I've some troubles to understand VisualBrush, DrawingBrush, and ImageBrush. Maybe it's easier to understand the purpose of these brushes. What are the best practices for these brushes? Are there any canonical examples? When should I use these brushes?

Comment: Why are you counting ImageBrush twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good page about the different WPF brushes in the MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa970904.aspx). Have you seen that yet? Maybe this will answer a few of your questions